# setting UINavigationBar tintColor only sets it's back button color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

SO I am setting a UINavigationBar tintColor and here's what I get:

[image]

```
[navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

How is this even possible? Here's some more info if it helps:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got a `UINavigationController` that I customize as follows:

First, come up with a 44px-high image as the background for the nav bar. (In this case, if you wanted to use a 44px-high white image, that'd do the trick --- but it'll look much nicer if you use some type of vertical gradient)

Second, use the following code in your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunching` method. (The image is called "`background_44.png`".

```
// Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
    UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_44.png"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

// Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Or you can check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706584/why-cant-i-set-a-custom-color-tint-for-the-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

I dropped that code in my project, worked fine. Even changed bar styles and colors. No problem. This line of code is fine, there is an issue somewhere else or its some crazy glitch.